# Not able to create nested packages inside my Oracle PL/SQL programs

Tags: oracle, plsql

In my requirement I need to create multiple sub-folders/Packages inside packages in Oracle Sql developer. I tried all the possible way but still I am not able to do this. The folder hierarchy should be looks like below.

- PACKAGES-->PACKAGE1-->SUB PACKAGE/SUB FOLDER,
- PACKAGES-->PACKAGE2-->SUB PACKAGE/SUB FOLDER

Could someone please help me on this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: A package neither contains folders, nor "sub-packages"

Answer (score 1):

A SUBpackage? What would that be? Package contains functions, procedures, variables, types, ... but another packages? I've never heard of that and it - apparently - won't work:

```
SQL> create or replace package a1 as
  2    procedure prc;
  3
  4    package pkg;
  5  end;
  6  /

Warning: Package created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PACKAGE A1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ---------------------------------------------------
4/11     PL/SQL: Declaration ignored
4/11     PLS-00201: identifier 'PKG' must be declared
SQL> l4
  4*   package pkg;
SQL> c/pac/-- pac
  4*   -- package pkg;
SQL> l
  1  create or replace package a1 as
  2    procedure prc;
  3
  4    -- package pkg;
  5* end;
SQL> /

Package created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Docs for sub-programs (which are always a function or procedure) https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-13BEBBEC-02D4-48E8-A059-DFEAC4751A3B

Comment: OK, no problem with that. I understood that the OP wants to create packages within packages.

Comment: No problem at all, Jeff :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Is there any possible way to create folder inside package?

Comment: We don't speak the same language, I'm afraid. **Folder** means "operating system, a *container* for Word files, MP3 files, JPGs etc.". **Package** means "database, a *container* for procedures, functions etc.". There's no "folder" in *database*. If you think it is, could you, please, explain what you mean?